# Writing $0$ as $0^2\div 0^1$ gives $0\div 0$. Does that make $0$ undefined?

Tags: definition, real-numbers, exponentiation

$0$ is a unique real number which means that it is a definite number, right?

$$0^2 = 0\times0 = 0$$

$0\div 0$ is considered as not defined.

So, if I write $0$ as $0^2\div0^1$ then that will become $0\div0$. Does that mean that now $0$ is undefined?

Comment: No, $0$ is of course defined. But $\frac{0^2}{0^1}$ is undefined because it is nothing else than $\frac{0}{0}$ hence the denominator is $0$, which is forbidden.

Comment: In other words, the exponentiation laws do not hold for base $0$. The base must be positive.

Comment: You could also write $1 = \frac{1^2}{1}$, but that does not mean $\frac{1}{1}$ would be undefined.

Comment: "if I write $0$ as $0^2÷0^1$ then that will become 0÷0.” This proves that you CAN'T write $0$ as $0^2÷0^1$.

Comment: I you write $0^2\div 0=0,$ it doesn’t make it true.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri your case is different. Division by 1 is defined. So 1 remains defined

Comment: @Peter Ah, ok... The fact that exponential laws don't work for base 0 makes the logic behind my theory incorrect. This makes sense. Since we can't use base 0 for exponential laws, you can't express 0 in the form of exponents. I get it now

Comment: @Obinna maybe, maybe. Your whole question just makes absolutely no sense, as you are defining something as something undefined and then obtaining that the thing you defined as that is undefined.

Comment: Why would writing a number/concept in a non-meaningful way make that number/concept non-meaningful?

Comment: @ryang I had assumed that exponential laws work if base is taken as 0. Now that I have learnt that my assumption was wrong, I agree that my logic was incorrect.

Comment: @ryang If I had known that writing a fraction with denominator 0 is non meaningful, then why would I have asked the question in the first place? Point is, earlier I didn't know that what I had written was non meaningful. Now I do.

Comment: You pointed out that $0\div0$ is undefined. And you also implicitly indicated that you think that $0\div0$ and $0^2\div0^1$ are equivalent. Then you wonder whether, therefore, writing $0$ as $0^2\div0^1$ (which you have indirectly noted is non-meaningful) makes $0$ undefined.   Well, we don't need exponential laws to refute your suggestion: if you make a false claim, and then logically derive a conclusion from that false claim, then whether that conclusion is actually true or false remains up in the air. That's all jjagmath, Thomas, Nelli and I are just saying.

Comment: @ryang I thought 0¹ could be represented as 0^(2-1), which is nothing but 0²÷0¹ which is 0÷0.  So I wrongly arrived at the conclusion that 0=0÷0. 'Now' I got confused that how can we have 0 (a defined number) = 0÷0 (which is undefined).  At the time of writing this question I did not know that what I had written was wrong. I have already apologised for the faulty logic behind my claims. If the question irritates you so much you could go ahead and close it

Comment: @ryang And yes, this isn't the original that I had written. My question has been edited

Comment: @Obinna At no point in this thread was I annoyed nor indicated such. Everything that I said above is in the spirit of learning. P.S. Closing/dwnvoting this question never crossed my mind. And Welcome to this site!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Divison can be viewed as an operation derived from multiplication.

Then the quotient $a/b$ is defined as $a\cdot b^{-1}$ where $b^{-1}$ is the inverse of $b$, i.e., $b\cdot b^{-1}=1$.
One can show that the inverse of a number, if existent, is uniquely determined. Therefore the writing $b^{-1}$ as the inverse of $b$.

If we talk about real numbers (any field), each number different from zero has an inverse. E.g., the inverse of $2$ is $1/2$.

Zero has no inverse, since zero is absorbing: $0\cdot a = 0$ for all $a$.

Comment: So you mean zero can't be uniquely determined?

Comment: No again. Zero is uniquely determined. We cannot however write in the above way since we cannot divide by $0$. What cannot be uniquely determined (and is therefore undefined) is $\frac{0}{0}$. It could be every number $r$ (it could even be non-real) since $r\cdot 0=0$ holds for every $r$.

Comment: And $\frac{1}{0}=r$ is neither allowed since this would mean $1=0\cdot r=0$ , a clear contradiction.

Comment: So basically we can't use 0 as the denominator, which means we can't represent any number as a fraction with  denominator 0, which further means we can't represent 0 as a fraction with denominator 0.

Comment: @Obinna Exactly